# MassTransit AzureServieBus InvalidOperationException

Tags: .net-core, azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm having troubles with the AzureServiceBus. Sometimes (it happens randomly) when a command or event is thrown to the bus I get this exception (image below) and the command/event its not fired so I miss it.

Also, sometimes the exception says that the service unsubscribed from some topics.

Has it happened to someone?

[Exception logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue40q.png)

Startup Configuration:

```
 services.AddScoped<IHostedService, MassTransitHostedService>();

 //Create Autofac ContainerBuilder 
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        containerBuilder.Populate(services);

        // register ApplicationModule (contains all modules for application)
        containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new ApplicationModule(Configuration));

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(containerBuilder.Build());
```

Bus configuration:

```
   protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
            {
    builder.Register(y => new ConsumerAndDeliver(y.Resolve<IIncomingMessageDeliver>())).As<ConsumerAndDeliver>().SingleInstance();

                builder.Register(c =>
                {
                    IComponentContext ctx = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
                    var consumer = ctx.Resolve<ConsumerAndDeliver>();
                    var bus = CreateBusInAzureServiceBusToRegister(consumer);
                    return bus;
                })
                    .As<IBusControl>()
                    .As<IPublishEndpoint>()
                    .As<ISendEndpointProvider>()
                    .SingleInstance();

                RegisterQueuesForCommands();
            }


  private IBusControl CreateBusInAzureServiceBusToRegister(object consumer)
    {
        var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(sbc =>
        {
            var host = sbc.Host(_configuration["myConnectionString"], h =>
                { });
            sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, _configuration["myQueueName"], e =>
            {
                e.Instance(consumer);
            });
        });
        return bus;
    }
```

HostedService for managing bus life cycle

```
public class MassTransitHostedService : Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService
    {
        private readonly IBusControl _busControl;

        public MassTransitHostedService(IBusControl busControl)
        {
            _busControl = busControl;
        }

        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await _busControl.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await _busControl.StopAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }
    }
```

Send and publish methods:

```
private readonly ISendEndpointProvider _commandSendEndpoint;
    private readonly IPublishEndpoint _eventPublishEndpoint;

private async Task DispatchMessageToBus<T>(T message, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    dynamic msg = message;
    switch (message)
    {
        case IOutcomingCommand outcomingCommand:
            var type = outcomingCommand.GetType();
            await _commandSendEndpoint.Send(outcomingCommand, type, cancellationToken);
            break;
        case IOutcomingEvent _:
            await _eventPublishEndpoint.Publish(msg, cancellationToken);
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Dispatch message must be IOutcomingCommand or IOutcomingEvent");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is closing the connection? Are you awaiting the Publish/Send methods?

Comment: The service is running in K8s and the pod is alive, so I dont know what is closing the conneciton because we only close it when the service stops. I paste some of the code that we use. Yes we await the Publish/Sends methods.

Comment: Container configuration is where most mistake happen, I'd suggest using the built-in container support for Autofac: https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/autofac.html

Comment: We use that documents for the configuration. We use modules. The only thing that we miss from there is that we dont use 'AddMassTransit' .